# How to prepend a text of string to a content_type's field?

Tags: entities, 8

For my assignment I have to write a module that when enabled will prepend a text of string "Hello World" to the body of a text field of hello_world_article content type.

I first tried to use Drupal 8 config export to try to set a default value (hello World) by using a yml file. However I get an error enabling the module that " field.field.node.hello_world_article.body already exists in active configuration."

My yml file is:

```
uuid: 42c51471-d897-4cb1-ac37-b2b6cddc6f0e58
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.body
    - node.type.hello_world_article
  module:
    - text
_core:
  default_config_hash: e_0gHBXrh9sHHe-XksjIYpOmFEiugHbtoJdYPxbftAI
id: node.hello_world_article.body
field_name: body
entity_type: node
bundle: hello_world_article
label: Body
description: ''
required: false
translatable: true
default_value:
  -
    summary: ''
    value: "<p><em>Hello World!</em></p>\r\n\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n"
    format: basic_html
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  display_summary: true
field_type: text_with_summary
```

How else would I get about approaching this problem. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to uninstall module first and the install it again!

Comment: I tried that. The field is defined in another yaml file. However I have to use my module for that.

Comment: Posting because I'm curious.. Why would using JavaScript in this case not be a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Create a template override for the field. Because it sounds like a class assignment, I'll leave the actual coding to you.